# Prove all $x(t)$ for a 2nd order homogeneous ODE with $x(0) = 0$, $x'(0) = 0$ are zero

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

We have an IVP ODE:

$$x''(t) + px'(t) + qx(t) = 0$$

and we know $x(0) = 0$ and $x'(0) = 0$.

Is it possible to say anything about the general particular solution of this equation?

Can we say $x(t) = 0$ for all $t$?

How to prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

If $p$ and $q$ are real numbers, you can study the possible solutions according to the characteristic equation:

\begin{align*}
r^{2} + pr + q = 0
\end{align*}

If $\Delta = p^{2} - 4q > 0$, there are two real roots.

If $\Delta = p^{2} - 4q = 0$, there is one double real root.

If $\Delta = p^{2} - 4q < 0$, there are two complex conjugate roots.

The corresponding solutions can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#Homogeneous_equation_with_constant_coefficients).

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes. Thank you for the hint. Is the following proof correct ? So suppose the solutions to the characteristic equation are a1 and a2. Then if a1!=a2, the general solutions would be Ae^(t*a1) + Be^(t*a2) in which case both A and B must be zero according to initial values. Or if a1=a2, the general solution would be  Ae^(t*a1) + Be^(t*a2) where also both A and B must be zero. Therefore all solutions x(t) for all t must be equal to zero.

Comment: Do I need to account for when a1 and a2 are complex numbers ? or does the above proof cover that case as well?